# How to skip task in Airflow operator?

Tags: python, airflow-scheduler, airflow

Is there a way for Airflow to skip current task from the PythonOperator? For example:

```py
def execute():
    if condition:
        skip_current_task()

task = PythonOperator(task_id='task', python_callable=execute, dag=some_dag)
```

And also marking the task as "Skipped" in Airflow UI?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Figured it out! Skipping task is as easy as:

```py
def execute():
    if condition:
        raise AirflowSkipException

task = PythonOperator(task_id='task', python_callable=execute, dag=some_dag)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to skip a task:

```py
def execute():
    if condition:
        return

task = PythonOperator(task_id='task', python_callable=execute, dag=some_dag)
```

Unfortunately, it will mark task as `DONE`

Comment: Well yes, but I need to know whether the task was ended successfully or skipped when I look in the Airflow UI